# python - why does Tkinter work only in interactive environments?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

I've just started experimenting with Tkinter, and I have some questions due to some peculiarities I've noticed.

First of all, I tried to use an interactive python environment and I typed the following:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> win = tkinter.Tk()
```

and a new window correctly appeared on my screen.

Then I tried to do the same creating a .py script:

```
import tkinter
win = tkinter.Tk()
```

and this is the error I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter
  File "/home/***/tests/tkinter.py", line 2, in <module>
    win = tkinter.Tk()
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk'
```

which I cannot explain: why the tkinter module exists and works ok in an interactive environment but it fails if I put the code in a script? Btw, I run the script with the command `python3.7 tkinter.py` and I use the command `python3.7` to run the interactive python shell.

After that I tried a more simple program (in the same script, but I deleted the **pycache** folder created: I must admit that I'm writing here ignoring its purpose):

```
import tkinter

print("Hello")
```

which prints *hello* **twice**. So I removed the `import tkinter` line. It prints *Hello* only once.

I sincerely cannot explain this strange behavior. I'm looking for someone who can.

Thanks.

Comment: Change your file name from "tkinter.py" to something else, e.g. "my_example.py"

Comment: You are importing your own py file I suspect. Rename the file. "Hello" getting printed twice is once for when the file is ran and once for when the file is imported thus the print-ception :D

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the problem. Renaming the file and re-running python worked as expected. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the exception details, you are importing your own "tkinter.py" file as a module instead of Tkinter library when running `import tkinter` line from the "tkinter.py". `Tk()` is not defined in your "tkinter.py" file and calling it causes the `AttributeError`. The same thing happens in the second example with `print("Hello")` - it runs twice: firstly, when you are importing your file, and secondly, when you are calling `print("Hello")` after this.

Rename your file from "tkinter.py" to something else, e.g. "my_example.py" to fix this problem.